# Qt: QIcon disappears when clicked; QIcon::Mode not being respected

Tags: c++, qt

I have a png format image of a [play button](http://www.iconsdb.com/green-icons/play-icon.html) in  which I have stored as an [embedded resource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) in my application.

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
  <qresource prefix="icon">
    <file>play.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I have created a `QIcon` with the same source image set for both `Normal` and `Active` modes

```
QIcon play;
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Normal);
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Active);
```

From what I understand, this should display the icon when unclicked (`Normal` mode), and continue doing so when clicked (`Active` mode)

> `QIcon::Normal`: Display the pixmap when the user is not interacting with the icon, but the functionality represented by the icon is available.
>
> `QIcon::Active`: Display the pixmap when the functionality represented by the icon is available and the user is interacting with the icon, for example, moving the mouse over it or clicking it.

However, when I click on it it disappears (a blank box being displayed instead).

Here is the icon unclicked

[image]

Here is the icon clicked

[image]

**Minimal working example:**

I have created a minimal example replicating the behaviour I see

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>

void initIcons()
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(view);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow*  window = new QMainWindow();

    QMenuBar* menu = new QMenuBar();
    window->setMenuBar(menu);

    QIcon play;
    play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Normal);
    play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Active);

    QAction* action = new QAction(play, "", nullptr);
    menu->addAction(action);

    window->show();
    return app->exec();
}
```

---

**Update:**

I have also tried every combination of `Mode` and `State` with no change in behaviour:

```
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Normal,   QIcon::On);
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Normal,   QIcon::Off);
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Selected, QIcon::On);
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Selected, QIcon::Off);
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Active,   QIcon::On);
play.addFile(":icon/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Active,   QIcon::Off);
```

I also tried [`addPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#addPixmap)

```
QIcon play;
play.addPixmap(QPixmap(":icon/play.png"), QIcon::Normal,   QIcon::On);
play.addPixmap(QPixmap(":icon/play.png"), QIcon::Normal,   QIcon::Off);
play.addPixmap(QPixmap(":icon/play.png"), QIcon::Selected, QIcon::On);
play.addPixmap(QPixmap(":icon/play.png"), QIcon::Selected, QIcon::Off);
play.addPixmap(QPixmap(":icon/play.png"), QIcon::Active,   QIcon::On);
play.addPixmap(QPixmap(":icon/play.png"), QIcon::Active,   QIcon::Off);
```

None of these alter the behaviour at all unfortunately.

Comment: What working well for me so that's strange. Did you try to add the pixmap in Active mode too ? with void QIcon::addFile(const QString &fileName, const QSize &size = QSize(), Mode mode = Normal, State state = Off) with mode = Active. so like that: icon.addFile(":/play.png", QSize(), QIcon::Active);

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard thanks for the comment. I have updated the question to reflect your suggestion. Unfortunately still not having any success with this

Comment: looks like you need create separate projects with one window and one button, so others can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @user1034749 I have updated the question with a minimal working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I understand in style of QMenuBar,
I modified your example in such way:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow*  window = new QMainWindow();

    QMenuBar* menu = new QMenuBar();
    menu->setStyleSheet(R"style(
QMenuBar {
   background-color: transparent;
}
QMenuBar::item:selected { /* when selected using mouse or keyboard */
  background: #a8a8a8;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed {
  background: #888888;
}
)style");
    window->setMenuBar(menu);

    QIcon play;
    const char path_to_icon[] = "/home/evgeniy/Downloads/icon-play-128.png";
    play.addFile(path_to_icon, QSize(), QIcon::Normal);
    play.addFile(path_to_icon, QSize(), QIcon::Active);

    QAction* action = new QAction(play, "", nullptr);
    menu->addAction(action);

    window->show();
    return app->exec();
}
```

and after press I can see icon.
Note that my default style is different then yours,
so you may need modify colors in stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes, it does seem to be an issue with the stylesheet and the default Unity theme in Ubuntu. In fact by setting the stylesheet for `QMenuBar::item:pressed` alone I was able to fix it. Do you know if it's possible to get what the stylesheet that would have been applied is?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add icon in SLOT:

```
connect({your_action_name},&QAction::toggled,[=](){
your_action_name.setIcon("icon_path_file.ico");
})
```

Comment: This is a question or an answer, if it is a question this is not a suitable place for it, please delete your post since this place is for answers only.